# How to do no higlight search in a mapping?

Tags: neovim, highlight

I want to write some mappings so I can move faster between the code. The problem is that I have hlsearch on(and i don't want it off) so I did it like this:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    nnoremap <Leader>r /return<CR>:noh<CR>
    nnoremap <Leader>nf /def .*(.*):<CR>:noh<CR>
    nnoremap <Leader>pf ?def .*(.*):<CR>:noh<CR>
    nnoremap <Leader>nc /class<CR>:noh<CR>
    nnoremap <Leader>pc ?class<CR>:noh<CR>
```

I added `:noh<CR>` to disable highlighting after search, but that makes "flickering" effect which is unpleasing.

Is there a way to disable highlighting just for the next search or other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a search without setting any highlight with the `:h search()` function.

For example, this will jump to the next occurrence of a 'return' preceded by optional space characters only:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :call search("\s*return")<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like [vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) for this. It doesn't exactly achieve what you want, because it (instead) automatically runs `:nohlsearch` when the cursor moves, or various other things. I've found it far more intuitive than dealing with various possible manual ways.